# list of all functions/procedures called by each function/procedure in an oracle package

Tags: oracle, plsql

is there a table in oracle that lists all functions/procedures called by each function/procedure in an Oracle package? I wanted to know how each function/procedure is related to other functions/procedures within the package, and the connection between each of them.

Comment: You can generate this information using the PLSCOPE compiler flag. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_plscope.htm#BABBJEBB)

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at all_dependencies/user_Dependencies/dba_dependencies and filter out by the object_type